Taylor series of $\arctan((1-x)/(1+x^2))$
What is the Taylor series around $a=1$ of :
$$\arctan\left(\dfrac{1-x}{1+x^2}\right)$$
I’m pretty convinced that by substitution of the $x$ we would try to find a series around $0$.
And perhaps knowing that
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\arctan(x)\right) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}\\
\arctan(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$
But I’m a bit confused, any help would be welcome.

It’s x^2, I edited the title, I don’t know why my latex doesn’t work

See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

The word is "series".  Both, the singular and the plural of the noun are "series".

Title and main body do not match.

Your latex doesn't work because you need to enclose the formulas in $...$ or $$...$$ . See here.

I see, now every thing should be good. Thank you for helping me formatting, now will see if anyone has an idea.

The series is the integral of the derivative
$$\frac{d}{dx}\tan{-1}\left( \frac{1-x}{1+x^2}\right)=\frac{-1-2 x+x^2}{2-2 x+3 x^2+x^4}$$
setting $x\ to -y -1 $
$$\frac{-2+y^2}{4-8 y+9 y^2-4 y^3+y^4}$$
that can be composed by the Taylor series of the denominator
  Series[1/(4 - 8 y + 9 y^2 - 4 y^3 + y^4), {y, 0, 12}] // Normal

$$\frac{1}{4}+\frac{y}{2}+\frac{7 y^2}{16}-\frac{35 y^4}{64}-\frac{25 y^5}{32}-\frac{113 y^6}{256}+\frac{21 y^7}{64}+\frac{1029 y^8}{1024}+\frac{525 y^9}{512}+\frac{935 y^{10}}{4096}-\frac{475 y^{11}}{512}-\frac{26131 y^{12}}{16384}$$
Removing the powers of two in the denomiator yields
$$\{1, 4,7,0,-35,-100,-113,168,1029,2100,935,-7600,-26131\}$$
